# Getting next record in SQLite database for mobile application

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, actionscript

I have a mobile application that uses an sqlite database.  I cannot seem to figure out how to access the next record when the user presses the 'next' button.  My database is using 'id' as primary key with autoincrement as integer.

```
    private function nextMoveRPart(event:EffectEvent):void
        {
            var cardNumber:int = parseInt(cardNumberLabel.text);

            stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
            conn.open(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("FlashCards.db"));
            stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM cardItems WHERE id = ?" + "AND id <= MAX(id)";
            stmt.parameters[0] = cardNumber+1;
            stmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, resultHandlerPrev);
            stmt.execute();
            conn.close();
            moveEffectRPart2.play();
        }
        function resultHandlerNext(event:SQLEvent):void  // result handler next
        {
            var result:SQLResult = stmt.getResult();
            var numResults:int = result.data.length;
            for(var i:int = 0; i < numResults; i++)
            {
                var row:Object = result.data[i];
                stext1.text = row.cSide1;
                stext2.text = row.cSide2;
                cardNumberLabel.text = row.id;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always store current id in some variable in ActionScript. Then You will be able to rewrite the whole query string. I think You can write something like this:

```
stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM cardItems WHERE id > " + current_id + " ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;";
```

The `current_id` is an ActionScript variable. This should be good enough for sqlite. You may set `current_id` to 0 for the first record. If a user click a next button, You should store there current id from the already received record.

The second option is to use `OFFSET`. It exclude some records from the beginning of returned set of rows.

```
stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM cardItems ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET " + your_offset + ";";
```

The `your_offset` is an ActionScript variable. It is `0` if You want get the first record, `1` for second, `2` for third and so on.

===

Try this code.

```
protected function button6_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void  // pushed --> button 
        {

            var cardNumber:int = parseInt(cardNumberLabel.text);
            /* Deleted */
            var sqlresult:SQLResult = stmt.getResult();
            stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
            conn.open(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("FlashCards.db"));
            /*Edited two lines*/
            stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM cardItems WHERE id > ? ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1";
            stmt.parameters[0] = cardNumber;
            stmt.execute();
            trace(sqlresult.data);  // value = [object Object]
            stext1.text = sqlresult.data.cSide1;
            trace(sqlresult.data.cSide1);  // value = 'undefined'
            cardNumberLabel.text = sqlresult.data.id;
            trace(sqlresult.data.id);  // value = 'undefined'
            conn.close();
            moveEffectRPart1.play();
            moveEffectRPart1.addEventListener(EffectEvent.EFFECT_END, nextMoveRPart);

        }
```

Comment: @Michas, would I store it using SQL? Or in actionscript.  Sorry I'm pretty new to both still.

Comment: @Michas, I've edited my post to show what I have, but I'm getting an error that says the 'index specified for parameter was out of range'.

Comment: What are these two lines for:
            stmt.text = "IDENT_CURRENT('cardItems') = ?";
            stmt.parameters[0] = current_id;

Comment: @Michas, i was trying to get the current id into a variable.  After some more looking around here's what I currently have.  ( posted up top ).

Comment: @Michas, my ultimate goal is to get the contents of the next record into textareas on the View.

Comment: This will also allows pushing to components.