# Using Flex to implement a "Next" or "Prev" button from an SQLite database

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite

I'm trying to get my local sqlite db to display the next record on the click of a button.

I've looked at posts like [Getting next record in SQLite database for mobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133767/getting-next-record-in-sqlite-database-for-mobile-application), but their code has offered little solution for me. Here is a sample of my code:

AS3:

```
    private function getNext():void
        {
            nextRecordId = targetRecordId + 1;

            selectStmt = new SQLStatement();
            selectStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
            var sql:String = "SELECT [Index], Title, CAST(Picture AS ByteArray) AS Picture FROM Data WHERE [Index] = 1" ;
            /*  selectStmt.parameters[@nextRecordId] = nextRecordId;  */ // Id of next record
            selectStmt.text = sql;
            selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult2);
            selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError2);
            selectStmt.execute();

        }

        private function selectResult2(event:SQLEvent):void
        {
            selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult2);
            selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError2);

            var result2:SQLResult = selectStmt.getResult(); 

            dataField2 = new ArrayCollection(result2.data);
            dp2 = ArrayCollection(dataField);  

            if (result2.data != null) 
            {
                pngIndex = result2.data[0].Index;
                pngTitle = result2.data[0].Title;
                pngByteArray = result2.data[0].Picture; 
                displayPic.source = pngByteArray;
            }   
        }
```

UI MXML:

```
    <s:Scroller interactionMode="touch"
            width="640"
            height="830">   
        <s:Group>
            <s:Image id="displayPic"
                     x="0" y="16" 
                     width="640" 
                     scaleMode="stretch" 
                     smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high"
                     />
            <!--<s:TextArea x="9" y="731" text="@{pngTitle}"/>-->
    </s:Group>
</s:Scroller>
```

Thanks a lot for the help/advice

Comment: Just to clarify, I am looking for how to call the next record from the database, as well as the equivalent of the Android "handler" to update the UI. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you're having problems with this.  Have you tried this thing called google?

```
selectStmt = new SQLStatement();
selectStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
selectStmt.text = "SELECT Title, CAST(Picture AS ByteArray) AS Picture FROM Data WHERE id=@index LIMIT 1";
selectStmt.parameters['@index'] = index++;
selectStmt.execute();
```

As long as you keep that index variable as a class var set at 0 for default, you should be fine until it runs out of rows.  Of course, there are other ways of doing this, like getting an array of all rows and have actionscript manage it.  This is easier if you don't have a very large database of information.

Comment: Yep, I've heard of google. And I've bookmarked 300+ pages about this stuff - I even offered the closest example I found to helping me out with this question and it wasn't much more help than anything else I had found. Thanks for the assistance, boo the snide commment.

It's not a big database, less than 100 records. I like the idea of using AS3 to manage this stuff - perhaps a little further on. How would I go about adding a search function? I'd need another variable in a different select statement, but do I have to reinitialize the sql statements every time I want to perform a function?

Comment: In case any other Newbs stop by:

Parameters have to be between "" or you will receive the infamous "property not defined" error. Ie: `selectStmt.parameters["@index"] = index++;`